# Rotating dendogram branches when you have thousands of them

Tags: r, dendextend

I have been working with the R package **dendextend** for producing a dendogram while being able to rotate some of its branches.
What I have is a dendrogram with more than 8000 branches. I want to flip some of the main ones, basically pivoting their connecting branch.
This is the code I am using:

```
 dend_columns = mat %>%
  t() %>%
  dist(method = "manhattan") %>%
  hclust(method = "ward.D") %>%
  dendextend::rotate(8265:1)
```

where `mat` is a 66x8265 matrix of values in the range of 0 and 1. Now, this code simply produces the mirror image of the dendogram through the `rotate()` function. But what if I want to rotate specific branches only?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Based on what I can read in [the documentation](https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2022-07-01/web/packages/dendextend/dendextend.pdf) of `rotate`, you'll need to specify the order in which you will want your branches.